# Distribute Custom B2B iOS app through Apple Volume Purchase Program?

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-vpp

Our requirement is to distribute iOS app for more than 1000+ users within the Organization.

My question : Can we make **Distribution iPA using iOS Developer Provisioning Profile** (As We have $99 Apple Account Not Enterprise Account) and share it with VPP and Apple MDM (Memory Device Management) or should i opt for Enterprise Apple account ?

**Note1 - Dont want to use Adhoc Provisioning Profile as it require all devices registered in apple account and we have 1000+ Apple Devices.

**Note2 - Already gone through other related post but dint find the steps to disbtribute the iOS using VPP , all post suggest to use Enterprise Distribution (Our requirement is to use VPP since Our business customer have already have VPP )

**Note3 - We have developed an iOS app , not want to share purchased app through VPP .
Kindly Suggest any reference which guides me to deploy App through VPP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the one organisation is both the developer and the consumer of the app, then an enterprise program membership is a possible approach.  With an enterprise membership you can:

- Develop apps
- Sign those apps for private distribution
- Distribute those apps, without going through the Apple approval process
- Distribute those apps via a private app store/intranet/MDM system etc.

If you want to provide apps to one or more enterprise customers that are independent of the developer then an individual membership and B2B distribution is the correct approach.  The steps are outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) but in summary:

- You develop your app as you normally would
- You create an entry for that app in iTunes connect, specifying *Available privately as a custom B2B app* in the *Pricing and availability* section
- You can also specify the price tier that applies to this app.  You can select the free tier and arrange payment directly with the customer if you prefer.
- Nominate an AppleID associated with the VPP customer you are going to supply to
- Submit the app for Apple approval as per usual

  **2019 addendum**

It is now possible for an organisation to provide B2B apps to themselves. The advantage of B2B apps is that they never expire and don't require periodic provisioning profile validation and refresh. The disadvantage is that there is still a review process, so if you are doing things that won't pass review you can have an issue. The review process also introduces some release delay.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can we use iOS Developer $99 apple account's distribution provisioning profile to create iPA and shared through VPP .

Comment: Yes, that is the individual membership to which I referred. You distribute through the VPP by creating a B2B app. VPP purchasers can also acquire any app that is publicly available on the iTunes Store;

Comment: Thanks Accepted +1

Comment: i dont want to make our app live on appstore but want to put it for review once approve , how can i make this app visible in my vpp account or our hosted website any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I got Complete Help from this link : https://chaione.com/blog/what-is-apples-b2b-app-store-and-how-does-it-work/ . Solved it and distributed app through VPP.

Comment: I am not clear on the enrollment costs for the developer business side of the B2B (ios B2B programme) and the recipient business (enrollment to VPP) ? I see that since 2012 or so there is no longer a 9.99USD minimum for any single app made available via VPP. However, is there a minimum voucher pre-pay spend required for a business to purchase to be able to participate ? Effectively I am looking for any participation costs for either side of the B2B participants. From skimming stuff on the web it appears to me like 99USD p/annum as per regular dev sub and zero initial cost on recipients ?

Comment: When i upload app with B2B,then how people can install the app.Do admin need to know apple ID of all user? @Paulw11

Comment: The simplest way is for the organisation to use an MDM to push the app to their managed devices.  If you don't have an MDM then you can download voucher codes that can be sent to individuals to redeem through the app store.  The other advantage of an MDM is that you can re-use licenses by transferring removing the app from one device and installing it on another, with the codes once a code is redeemed it is "owned" by the apple id of the user that redeems the code and it cannot be transferred to another employee.