# Developer ID certificate for iOS

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

My customer has been unable to install my iPad app via the MDM they're using, and I'm thinking it's because I've signed it for Ad Hoc Distribution. They recommend I resign it with a Developer ID certificate; however, that option appears to only be for macOS:

[image: Create a New Certificate]

I went ahead and had my "Team Admin" generate one, and I confirmed that it works with macOS apps (doesn't even require a provisioning profile) and not with iOS ones. Is there a way to generate a Developer ID certificate for iOS?

My follow-on question is: how should I be signing it, assuming I don't want to submit to the App Store?

Comment: If they want to distribute the app via an MDM then they either need an enterprise build or an App Store build. If they don't have an enterprise developer program membership then a custom B2B app is probably the simplest. You creste an app entry in AppStore Connect as usual but you set the distribution to "custom B2B" app and nominate the customer. They need to enrol in Apple Business Manger. You then upload a standard App Store build and submit it for review. Once approved the customer can download it in Apple Business Manager and distribute via MDM

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841780/distribute-custom-b2b-ios-app-through-apple-volume-purchase-program/38843595#38843595

Comment: Perfect, that's the conclusion I have come to in my research thus far, but they are pretty sure they have never done that for any of their other apps. I am currently waiting for a response from a group who has successfully delivered to them.

Comment: An ad hoc build would need to contain a provisioning profile with the UDID of every device they wanted to deploy to